# Getting SQLiteContraintException in Android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm getting a constraint failed exception in my Android project, and I can't quite figure out where it's coming from. My helper class looks like this:

```
    public static final String WORDS_TABLE = "words";
public static final String ATT_WORD = "word";
public static final String ATT_T1 = "T1";
public static final String ATT_T2 = "T2";
public static final String ATT_T3 = "T3";
public static final String ATT_T4 = "T4";
public static final String ATT_T5 = "T5";
public static final String ATT_RECENT = "recent";
public static final String ATT_RATING = "rating";

public static final String STATISTICS_TABLE = "statistics";
public static final String ATT_GAMESPLAYED = "gamesPlayed";
public static final String ATT_wordsCORRECT = "wordsCorrect";
public static final String ATT_wordsWRONG = "wordsWrong";
public static final String ATT_POINTTOTAL = "pointTotal";
public static final String ATT_WINS = "wins";
public static final String ATT_LOSSES = "losses";

public static final String SETTING_TABLE = "settings";
public static final String ATT_SID = "sid";
public static final String ATT_TYPE = "type";
public static final String ATT_DURATION = "duration";
public static final String ATT_PTSTOWIN = "ptsToWin";

public static final String CATEGORIES_TABLE = "categories";
public static final String ATT_CATEGORY = "category";

public static final String BELONGS_TABLE = "belongs";

public static final String USER_TABLE = "user";
public static final String ATT_UID = "uid";

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "taboo";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String WORDS_CREATE =
    "create table words (_id primary key autoincrement, word text, "
    + "T1 text, T2 text, T3 text, T4 text, T5 text, "
    + "recent integer, rating integer);";

private static final String CATEGORIES_CREATE =
    "create table categories (_id integer primary key autoincrement, category text unique);";

private static final String BELONGS_CREATE =    
    "create table belongs (_id integer primary key autoincrement, word text, category text, "
    + "foreign key (word) references words (word), foreign key (category) references categories (category));";

private static final String USER_CREATE =
    "create table user (_id integer primary key autoincrement, uid text unique);";

private static final String STATISTICS_CREATE =   
    "create table statistics (_id integer primary key  autoincrement, uid text unique, gamesPlayed integer, wordsCorrect integer, "
    +"wordsWrong integer, pointTotal integer, wins integer, losses integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));";

private static final String SETTINGS_CREATE =
    "create table settings (_id integer primary key autoincrement, uid text, sid text, "
    +"type text, duration integer, ptsToWin integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));"
    ;


//**************************************************************
//*********************  Function Constants ********************
//**************************************************************

private final Context context; 
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private int wordCount = 100;

//********************  Object 
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(WORDS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(CATEGORIES_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(BELONGS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(USER_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(STATISTICS_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SETTINGS_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
                          int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
              + " to "
              + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + WORDS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//****************************************************
//********  Database Functions  **********************
//****************************************************

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
} 
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

The population of my database table 'words' used JExcelAPI to scan from an excel spreadsheet the data to be entered. The populate method looks like this:

```
public void WordPopulate(Context ctx) throws SQLException, BiffException, IOException
{
    Workbook wb = null;
    AssetManager asst = ctx.getAssets();

    wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(asst.open("words.xls"));

    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);
    final int rows = sh.getRows() - 1;
    final int columns = sh.getColumns() - 1;

    Cell a1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= columns; j++) {
                a1 = sh.getCell(j,i);
                String str = a1.getContents();
                if (j == 1) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_WORD, str);
                if (j == 2) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_T1, str);
                if (j == 3) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_T2, str);
                if (j == 4) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_T3, str);
                if (j == 5) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_T4, str);
                if (j == 6) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_T5, str);
                if (j == 7) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_RECENT, (int)0);
                if (j == 8) content.put(DBAdapter.ATT_RATING, (int)0);
            }
            DBAdapter.db.insert(DBAdapter.WORDS_TABLE, "NULL", content);
        }
    }
```

I think all of the data in the spreadsheet is ok. Does anyone have any ideas on what would cause the SQLiteConstraintException? Thanks for the time

Comment: PS - it occurs for every instance of the insert statement in the loop. Here's an example of the LogCat output - ERROR/Database(28543): Error inserting T4=CITRUS T5=PILLS word=Vitamin C rating=0 T1=NUTRITION recent=0 T3=ORANGES T2=COLDS

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to add a duplicate unique value. That might be causing the `SQLiteConstraintException`.

Comment: The populate method only acts on the 'words' table, and I think the only unique constraint should be on _id, which should be autoincremented on each insert

Comment: That, or an invalid foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
private static final String WORDS_CREATE =
    "create table words (_id primary key autoincrement, word text, "
    + "T1 text, T2 text, T3 text, T4 text, T5 text, "
    + "recent integer, rating integer);";
```

should be

```
private static final String WORDS_CREATE =
    "create table words (_id integer primary key autoincrement, word text, "
    + "T1 text, T2 text, T3 text, T4 text, T5 text, "
    + "recent integer, rating integer);";
```

Correction is "_id **integer** primary key".

Not an error, but for consistency, I think this

```
private static final String SETTINGS_CREATE =
    "create table settings (_id integer primary key autoincrement, uid text, sid text, "
    +"type text, duration integer, ptsToWin integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));"
    ;
```

should be

```
private static final String SETTINGS_CREATE =
    "create table settings (_id integer primary key autoincrement, uid text, sid text, "
    +"type text, duration integer, ptsToWin integer, "
    +"foreign key (uid) references user (uid));";
```

Change is position of final semicolon.